# Apply jQuery to created elements

Tags: jquery, append, lightbox

Maybe kind of a stupid question, but i'm a beginner in jQuery and i'm trying to make a lightbox with a form in it. So far so good, but now i want to make a validation on the created form, but that's the problem. I create the form via the following method:

```
 $("a").click(function(){
  if(this.rel == "box"){
   $("body").append('').append('');
   $("#shadowContent").append('Sluit venster - Your total price is €55,-').append('');
   $("#closeBox").click(function(c) {
    c.preventDefault();
    $("#shadow").add($("#shadowContent"),$("#closeBox")).fadeOut(500);
   });
   $("#shadow").add($("#shadowContent")).fadeIn(500);
   $("#shadowContent").show().css({'width':'750px','top':'25px','left':'50%','margin-left':'-400px'});
   $("#content").load('http://www.domain.nl/tmp/make');
```

Now when i try adding the following code, just below the above code, the form submits and i don't get the required alert.

```
   $("#reservationForm").submit(function(f){
    f.preventDefault();
    alert("Jawel");
   });
```

My form looks (simplified) like this:

```
<form id="reservationForm">
 <fieldset>
   <legend>Legend</legend>
     ...
  </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
   <legend>Legend</legend>
     ...
  </fieldset>
 <button type="submit">
</form>
```

The whole form is in a new document (make.php) which is loaded in my lightbox through jQuery. How can i apply a validation to the fields in my form? I want to keep my jQuery in one file, so it would be nice if i not have to place the validation in make.php itself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for what you want, like this:

```
$("#reservationForm").live("submit", function(f){
  f.preventDefault();
  alert("Jawel");
});
```

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event handlers work slightly different, they aren't on the elements themselves (it adds a handler to `document`), so it can work on *future* elements added to the page later by listening for their events to [bubble up](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html), events bubble the same way, regardless of when the elements were added.

Answer (score 0):

to auto bind events to dom created you can use `.live();`

```
eg:

jQuery('.red').live('click',_functionDoSomething);
```

now in future if you add more elements with class=red they will have function=_functionDoSomething alreday attached to them

Comment: To be clear this doesn't "autobind", it works off event bubbling, no actual code runs when DOM elements are added, it's completely passive.